# How to manually draw a mouse cursor on MacOS?

Tags: macos, mouse-cursor

For a screen sharing collaborative app, it is desirable to give the remote party a mouse cursor also.

Is it possible to leverage `NSCursor`?

If not, I guess I must create a small accurately positioned top-level window displaying a bitmap (*I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56304537/how-to-retrieve-the-backing-image-for-an-nscursor-arrowcursor-say-as-an-n) if there is some way to retrieve the bitmaps from the system cursors*).

Code/link contributions appreciated. If I figure it out first I will (as always) answer my own question.